# Missing Node tab on Monero GUI app v0.14.0? How do I set the daemon host?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

In Settings, I only see 3 tabs: Wallet, Layout and Info. I saw a screenshot in another question or article somewhere, with a 'Node' tab to set the daemon host - is this not available in Monero GUI app v0.14.0?

Comment: Which wallet mode did you choose?

Comment: I chose 'Simple mode'.

Comment: In wallet settings there should be an advanced mode checkbox.

Comment: There is no 'advanced mode' checkbox in any of the 3 tabs. Fyi, I opened the wallet from a .keys file that I browsed to.

Comment: I just re-did the process going the route of 'Create a new wallet from hardware device' > 'Restore a wallet from device' option and still no 'advanced mode' checkbox.

Comment: What about when you *don't* select 'Simple mode' in the wizard creating/restoring? Sorry I'm not being very helpful, I don't use the GUI.

Comment: I don't want to download the blockchain, just use a remote node/host.

Comment: Sure, but you can still use a remote node by *not* using 'Simple mode'.

Comment: @ncruz - Is your intend to use a specific remote node? Because then you need `Advanced mode`. However, if you simply want to automatically connect to a remote node, `Simple mode` is the preferred mode. The wallet mode selection screen is located after the language selection by the way (in the wizard).

Comment: dEBRUYNE, I just want the wallet sync/refresh to be faster. Looks like a have a misunderstanding of what a remote node/host is. The wallet is still not synched/refreshed.

Comment: @ncruz - Somehow did not gt a notification of your comment. I think your question is now properly answered here -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11369/missing-functionality-screen-controls-in-monero-gui-app-v0-14-0