# Missing functionality / screen controls in Monero GUI app v0.14.0

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I was browsing the getmonero.org website and saw a screenshot in the 'Creating A View-Only Wallet' guide. The screen had way more controls - menu tabs - than what I see on my GUI. Here is a comparison of both screenshots with the top image from the getmonero website with more screen controls high lighted in yellow:


[image]

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? Maybe some setting or config, or perhaps the unzip process skipped some files?

Comment: Is this not covered in the comments to your other [question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11339/missing-node-tab-on-monero-gui-app-v0-14-0-how-do-i-set-the-daemon-host)? Your wallet was opened/started in "Simple mode". The other settings/tabs you are not seeing are for running in "Advanced mode".

Comment: Thanks jtgrassie. There was no clear answer to that question. Why are other users only adding comments and not answers? Is answering a question not enabled? As to your question to my other question, my intent is not mainly to be able to use a remote node, but rather not to download the blockchain. Your comment of using a remote node by not using 'Simple mode' was not clear whether the other options where a remote node is used would result in the download of the blockchain. The bottom line is that I don't have room in my HD so I'm looking for a cold/hot wallet solution with no blockchain DL.

Comment: I cannot speak for others, but it is expected practice on SE to use comments for clarifying the questioners question, to enable getting to a clear question and therefore answer. For example, you have now posted 2 similar questions and only now clarified your intent via the comment thread(s). ;)

Comment: It's all good, I'm in the process of writing you an answer now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrepancy in your posted screenshots is based on what *mode* the wallet is being run in. The GUI wallet supports both "Simple" and "Advanced" modes. When in advanced mode, you have the extra tabs and menu items.

You can switch modes by clicking the "Close wallet" button, restarting the GUI and when in the opening wizard, open the existing wallet and change the mode to advanced mode (after language). You will then have all the advanced options available to you.

Per your comment above:

> my intent is not mainly to be able to use a remote node, but rather not to download the blockchain

Unfortunately it *is* a little confusing for new users understanding the various options/modes.

There are two different "simple" modes, one with bootstrap and one without. The key difference is that when using the bootstrap variety, the blockchain is downloaded to your computer at the same times as connecting you to a remote node, so you can use your wallet immediately, without needing to wait for the full blockchain to download.

Advanced mode allows for the fullest flexibility. Here you can specify if you want to download the full blockchain, use only a remote node, use a specific remote node, or use a mixture (e.g. bootstrap).

As your intent is to use a remote node and not store the whole blockchain, you can safely just use simple mode (without the bootstrap option). However, you cannot specify *which* remote node is used while in this mode. Therefore, if you want to specify a remote node yourself, you will need to have started your wallet in the advanced mode.

I'll end with pointing out one other thing. Although using a remote node, with no bootstrap, wont actually store the blockchain, it still needs to scan for outputs, which takes time and bandwidth. Depending on how long since you last scanned, this can take some time. This is why there are two progress bars. Wallet sync is the scan progress, daemon sync is the daemons download progress. If you are using a remote node (daemon), it shows how much the remote node has downloaded. If you are using a local node, it shows your local daemon download progress.

Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

@jtgrassie's reply is excellent, but here is an update on how to switch to these various modes with the latest version of monero GUI (v0.15.0.2 currently):

- Step 1: log out of your wallet, there is an icon in the upper left corner, or you can go to Settings and then there is an option to close the wallet.
  [image: monero-advanced-mode-step1]
- Step 2: Click on Change wallet mode
  [image: monero-advanced-mode-step1]
- Step 3: Choose your wallet mode:
  [image: monero-advanced-mode-step1]

Here is a description of each option:

- Simple mode: connects automatically to remote nodes, the blockchain is not downloaded. This reduces privacy (since your transactions are seen by the remote node, so you need to trust the remote node), but it's faster. Also you are dependent on remote nodes to process your transactions, so that they can be slower.
- Simple mode (bootstrap): mixed mode, connects to remote nodes but also downloads the blockchain in parallel, so you get faster transactions, and potentially better privacy (but I'm not sure whether the transactions gets treated by the remote node nevertheless).
- Advanced mode: allows you to later select in Settings > Node tab whether you want to run a local node (download the whole blockchain, currently at about 70 GB, this is very slow and takes days for the first setup but it's the best for privacy as your transactions aren't sent to a remote node, so it's fully anonymous) or connect to a remote node that **you choose** (for example from [here](https://moneroworld.com/)). Also, you can mine monero in the Advanced side pane tab. Note that in advanced mode, there is no boostrap option (mixing local and remote nodes), and there is no automatic remote node selection.

Then you can reopen your wallet (usually you want to select "Choose a wallet from file", Monero will automatically find your old wallet, see 2nd screenshot above) and the new mode will change the interface accordingly.